# How can I pass an altered Model to a Controller from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and having a rough time with this.  I have read many posts and books and done tutorials and I am now going to ask the public for help.

My situation:

I am upgrading part of a classic ASP website to MVC.  It is the FAQ portion of the website.

I've got a controller called FAQController and a View Result called, Display, that takes in the parameters Year and faqID and then displays the related FAQ information in the view.

I want to be able to have a user rate how helpful the FAQ was by clicking on a set of links or buttons that will look like stars (1-star through 5-star ratings)

I want the onclick event of the buttons to route to an [HttpPost] ViewResult that then stores the rating in a database and returns them to the previous view with whatever selection they made highlighted.  So if they click 4 stars after the information is submitted 4 stars would be highlighted.

So I have an int rating property in my model that I want to be able to change in the view, then update to a database, and then display the change once the view loads again.

My question is what is a good way to change the Rating value of the Model before I resubmit the model to the controller?

I see I can use @Html.Hiddenfor(m => Model.FAQRating) to get the value of the first model rating (which by default is 0) but how should I go about setting that value before I resubmit the form to the controller.

Am I even thinking about this correctly?  I thought I might be able to add a "rating" parameter to the Display view result but that seemed dumb.

Comment: my suggestion would be looking into ajax calls, and having javascript get the values on each click, and send it to the controller. i would give you a more specific answer, but I don't know what the html of your page looks like

Comment: Yeah I ended up using a JavaScript call to set the hidden values before I resubmitted the model..  I just wondered if there was a fancier way MVC could do it with the @Html helpers.